How to generate expo ipa file for ios (like apk in android) using expo eas
How to generate expo IPA file for iOS and install it on my physical iPhone for testing purposes (like apk file in Android) using expo eas.
What setting do I need to change in the below code for the ios IPA file?
  {
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 10.1.1"
      },
      "build": {
        "development": {
          "developmentClient": true,
          "distribution": "internal"
        },
        "preview": {
          "distribution": "internal"
        },
        "production": {}
      },
      "submit": {
        "production": {}
      }
    }



This page describes the process of building iOS projects with EAS Build : https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/ios-builds/

To generate an IPA file for iOS using Expo EAS, you need to add a build profile with the ios property and set buildType to archive or export.

Here is updated eas.json file
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
     },
     "preview": {
       "distribution": "internal"
     },
     "production": {},
     "ios": {
       "buildType": "export"
     }
   },
   "submit": {
     "production": {}
   }
}


You can run Command to generate the IPA file.
eas build -p ios 


Run eas build:status to get the URL of the generated IPA file.

Open the URL on your iPhone to download and install the IPA file.


